# Titanium Android: Getting evalJS() to work after ActionBar.onHomeIconItemSelected()

Tags: javascript, android, android-actionbar, timeout, titanium

Unless I'm just plain doing something wrong, something is broken on 5.0 (using Ti 3.3.0 or 3.4.1 — doesn't matter which.)

What I need to do is, after the home/back button is tapped on the `ActionBar`, have the app call into the `WebView`'s JS code. But it seems that on Android 5.0, any `evalJS()` after `onHomeIconItemSelected()` is called will result in a timeout.

```
app.js:

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: "Test",
    navBarHidden: false
});

var view = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url: "test.html"
});

win.add(view);

win.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    win.activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    var actionBar = win.activity.actionBar;
    actionBar.title = win.title;
    actionBar.displayHomeAsUp = true;
    actionBar.onHomeIconItemSelected = function() {
            win.fireEvent('mytest');
    };
});

win.addEventListener('mytest', function() {
    Ti.API.info("'mytest'");
    view.evalJS("doTest()");
});

win.open();


test.html:

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Tap the ActionBar back arrow.
</body>
</html>


test.js:

function doTest()
{
    Ti.API.info("doTest()");
}
```

Works on Android 4.4; subsequently broken on a device just upgraded to 5.0.

On Android 4.4, the output is the expected result:

```
[INFO] : 'mytest'
[INFO] : doTest()
```

But on Android 5.0, the output is:

```
[INFO] : 'mytest'
[WARN] : TiWebViewBinding: (KrollRuntimeThread) [50477,50477] Timeout waiting to evaluate JS
```

Note that doing it as an event isn't necessary to cause the timeout; I'm doing that because it caused other problems previously, so the way to overcome any context-related issues seemed to be to let the app handle it not in a UI callback. Replacing `win.fireEvent('mytest')` with `view.evalJS('doTest()')` directly makes no difference — the `evalJS()` call still times out.

Is there a way to getting this working on 5.0? Or can anyone suggest a decent workaround to call `evalJS()` post-`onHomeIconItemSelected()`?